# Convert array of userids into usernames using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP function that returns me the specific set of userids in an array. I want to create a function that will convert these userids into usernames. I know how I can create a query to convert each one and then run the query in a loop. But is there a better way that I can do it for the whole array. Like a single query that would accept multiple values or something. My Array is as simple as:

```
[0] => 126312
[1] => 128383
[2] => 987376
[3] => 563542
```

Comment: for insert, you can insert multiple records like: `INSERT INTO TableName VALUES ('$id1'), ('$id2'), ('$id3'), ...`

Comment: Not insert, I already have the Userid, I want the usernames for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a table called "user" and fields "id" and "username", you could do:
(see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in )

```
$ids = array( [0] => 126312
[1] => 128383
[2] => 987376
[3] => 563542);

// do pre logic, e.g connecting...

// sanitize input:
$ids = array_map( "intval", $ids );

$sql = "SELECT user.username FROM user WHERE user.id IN(". implode( ",", $ids ) .")";

// do fetch logic.
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning SQL. The IN statement works like the in_array() of PHP. Nice!